# GraphQL transforming time field to number

Tags: reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby, netlify

I have content in markdown files (generated in netlify cms) that looks like this:

[image] [image]

I'm not sure if the syntax highlighter in vs code is treating the values of `startTime` and `endTime` or if this is something with markdown itself or the way it is being created in netlify cms.

But either way graphQL seems to read one as a number and the other as a string:

[image]

I tried to create type definitions in `gatsby-node.js` as follows but when I check the console output I see that it is too late and it is been given the values 1200 and 1080 instead of 18:00 and 20:00

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions, schema }) => {
    const { createTypes } = actions
    const typeDefs = [
        schema.buildObjectType({
            name: 'MarkdownRemark',
            fields: {
                frontmatter: 'Frontmatter!'
            },
            interfaces: ['Node'],
            extensions: {
                infer: true,
            },
        }),
        schema.buildObjectType({
            name: 'Frontmatter',
            fields: {
                startTime: {
                    type: 'String!',
                    resolve(parent) {
                        console.log(parent.startTime);
                        return `${parent.startTime}`;
                    }
                },
                endTime: {
                    type: 'String!',
                    resolve(parent) {
                        console.log(parent.endTime);
                        return `${parent.endTime}`;
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
    ]
    createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

Is there some way I can specify in Netlify's config.yml not to treat this field as a number? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

This is how I declare the fields in config.yml:

```
- { label: "Start Time", name: startTime, widget: string}
- { label: "End Time", name: endTime, widget: string}
```

But now when I look in github I see some very strange results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config.yml` use the [`datetime` widget and the format options](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/widgets/datetime/) provided by Netlify:

```
- { name: startTime, label: "Start Time", widget: datetime, date_format: MM/DD/YYYY, time_format: false, format: L }
- { name: endTime, label: "EndTime", widget: datetime, date_format: MM/DD/YYYY, time_format: false, format: L },
```

Change your `date_format(MM/DD/YYYY)` for any desired format.

Keep in mind that Netlify `datetime` widget uses [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/), check their format options to get one that fits you.